# Can I use one mobile ad mediation(MoPub) on another mediation(Admob)?

Tags: mobile, admob, ads, mopub

I used Admob mediation for multiple mobile ad sources for a long time and everything goes well.
For some specific object, I need to add another mediation MoPub on Admob mediation.

Is it possible / reasonable?
Can I achieve that by implementing my own adapter?

I couldn't find any related information so I come to ask for help. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by creating an adapter.
Admob refers to them as CustomEvents.

Here is a good video on how to do so by one of the Google Admob Developer advocates.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07wM2ZXHobI

Comment: Thanks for the video! But I think the CustomEvent is designed for managing "AD Network". I wonder if the CustomEvent still works for managing another "Mediation"?

Comment: There is no difference as far as the CustomEvent knows.

Comment: Great I'll try it. But my only concern is MoPub Mediation can set keyword to request targeting AD, I think Admob don't support this kind of request. Is there any method for Admob to pass the keyword?

Comment: There used to be a AdView#setKeywords method. Not sure anymore.